# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory ,,,/theano/gpuarray/c_code/blockgemv.c

Tags: python, pyinstaller, theano

i write this code:

```
import theano
print('hello')
```

then run pyinstaller to make exe file. process finished, but when i run exe file, this error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tk_torch_test.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\deep1\anaconda3\envs\MultiFace\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 491, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "theano\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\deep1\anaconda3\envs\MultiFace\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 491, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\deep1\anaconda3\envs\MultiFace\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 491, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "theano\gpuarray\fft.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\deep1\anaconda3\envs\MultiFace\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 491, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "theano\gpuarray\opt.py", line 64, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\deep1\anaconda3\envs\MultiFace\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 491, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "theano\gpuarray\blocksparse.py", line 86, in <module>
  File "theano\gpuarray\blocksparse.py", line 32, in __init__
  File "theano\gof\op.py", line 1308, in __init__
  File "theano\gof\op.py", line 1331, in load_c_code
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Deep1\\Projects\\multifacetracker_exe\\dist\\VideoAnonymizer\\theano\\gpuarray\\c_code\\blockgemv.c'
```

- theano version: 1.0.4+unknown
- pyinstaller version: 4.0.dev0
- python version: 3.6
- os: windows 10

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If theano is installed in Lib\site-packages\theano, you need to create a hook-theano.py file with this content:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths
datas = [(get_package_paths('theano')[1],"theano"),]
```

and copy this file into your PyInstaller folder:

```
Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks
```

When you run pyinstaller, you need to add the path of mxnet with the -p option:

```
pyinstaller myApp.py -p <your-path-to-this-point>\Lib\site-packages
```

It will copy the entire mxnet folder into your dist output folder.